# inserting lines after specific line with loop

Tags: scripts

I have a text file as follows;

```
   SITE              FIX    --COORD.CONSTR.--  
      << default for regional stations >>
ALL               NNN    100.  100.   100.     
      << IGS core stations >>
VILL VILL_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
MAS1 MAS1_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
```

Firstly, I delete all defaults lines after "<< IGS core stations >>" with  this command;

```
sed -i '/GPS/d' ./text.data
```

Then I need to add user's input 4 characters id with above line format like;

```
echo -n "###ids?####" 
read ids
```

assume user input `brmu ista ankr`. Then text.data file needs to be as follows;

```
SITE              FIX    --COORD.CONSTR.--  
      << default for regional stations >>
ALL               NNN    100.  100.   100.     
      << IGS core stations >>
BRMU BRMU_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
ISTA ISTA_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
ANKR ANKR_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
```

How I can insert these inputs with loop into the text file with specific format as above?

Comment: Will the values always be `NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05`?

Comment: yes @terdon, it is

Comment: Is that the full file, or is there anything else after `<< IGS core stations >>` ? Could we just clear the rest of file, and promt user at command line for input ?

Comment: The full file is the file I gave in the example but the lines number after IGS core stations are variable but format same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use awk:

```
read ids
# some validation here...

awk -v input="$ids" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(toupper(input), user)
        fmt = "%-4s %-8s     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05\n"
    }
    {print}
    /<< IGS core stations >>/ {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf fmt, user[i], user[i]"_GPS"
        exit
    }
' ./text.data
```

outputs

```
   SITE              FIX    --COORD.CONSTR.--  
      << default for regional stations >>
ALL               NNN    100.  100.   100.     
      << IGS core stations >>
BRMU BRMU_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
ISTA ISTA_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
ANKR ANKR_GPS     NNN    0.050 0.050  0.05
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
sed -i '/GPS/d' text.data; read -p "###ids?####" ids; for i in $ids; do 
        printf '%s\t%s_GPS\tNNN\t0.050\t0.050\t0.05\n' "${i^^}" "${i^^}"
    done >> text.data
```

That will loop over each word in `$ids` and use `printf` to print it in the desired format. The `${i^^}` makes the variable UPPER CASE.

Comment: I tried your code but it just delete three lines after  << IGS core stations >> but there is no print after that

Comment: @deepblue_86 It's a typo in the answer, just replace the last line with `done >> text.data`.

Comment: @deepblue_86 yes, what kos said. I had used the wrong file name since that's the name I was using when I tested it.